# Where do get Microsoft Office Tasks " ------------" at the top from?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, iphone, exchange, ipad, tasks

This is very weird and I have not found any question on this on the net.

I am using MS Exchange 2013 and MS Office 2013 Pro 64bit. I am accessing the Exchange from Outlook 2013 and from iPhone and iPad.

I have disabled all Apple Outlook addons.

For about a year or so now, all tasks get within 24 hours of saving this text on their top

> "
>   ------------ "

It looks like a separator.

I suspect it may be put in by Apple iPhone Tasks synchronization but am not sure.

Does anybody else experienced this? How to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how cumbersome it may seem, it's an Outlook design issue having nothing to do with Apple products.

See this [blog entry](http://www.jiripik.net/Blog/Post/10/MS-Outlook-2013-Recurrent-%28e-g--weekly%29-Tasks-Are-Getting-%E2%80%9C--------%E2%80%9C-on-Recurrent-%28e-g--weekly%29-Completion).